# How to arrange random letters, characters, shapes, etc in a random shape using CSS, HTML and jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have attached mockups which I want to implement in HTML and then animate these to form a loader.[image]

I have tried to set the letter initially using Masonry JS. But I am not sure how to arrange these within a shape.

Can this be achieved by Three.JS or Particle.JS? I have just started with Three.JS but I am not sure if I am on a right track.

Also, I am not very much good at Adobe applications to make this as GIF or a video.

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/jagruti23/pen/rNJqYLr

```
HTML
<div class="flyingLetters"></div>

CSS
body {
  background: #010101;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items :center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flyingLetters {  
  display: flex;
  align-items :center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flyingLetters {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 10%
}
.animation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.animation-container span {
  color: whitesmoke;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px white;
  user-select: none;
  float: left;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 1;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 2px
}
jQuery

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 125; i++)
    text += "<span>" + possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)) + "</span>";

  return text;
}

// $(".flyingLetters").html(makeid());
'use strict';

var app = {

  chars: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],

  init: function () {
    app.container = document.createElement('div');
    app.container.className = 'animation-container';
    document.querySelector('.flyingLetters').appendChild(app.container);
    // window.setInterval(app.add, 100);
  },

  add: function () {
    var element = document.createElement('span');
    // element.className('letters');
    app.container.appendChild(element);
    app.animate(element);
  },

  animate: function (element) {
    var character = app.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * app.chars.length)];
    var duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    var offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - duration * 2)) + 3;
    var size = 10 + (15 - duration);
    element.style.cssText = 'left:' + offset + 'vw; font-size:' + size + 'px;animation-duration:' + duration + 's; transform: rotate(' + ((Math.random() + 100) * Math.random()) + 'deg)';
    element.innerHTML = character;
    // window.setTimeout(app.remove, duration * 1000, element);
  },

  remove: function (element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  },

};

app.init()

for (var i = 0; i < app.chars.length; i++) {
  app.add()
}
$(".animation-container").masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: 'span',
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', );
```

Comment: How about a slightly simpler alternative - fill the viewport with random characters then animate a clip-path on it.

Comment: Thank you @AHaworth. I will try this too and update the Codepen!